# NiFi ifelse invalid because returning a string instead of a boolean

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working on a NiFi workflow. JSON is coming into the workflow and I am using EvaluateJsonPath and RouteOnAttribute processes. In the EvaluateJsonPath, I have the **Null Value Representation** set to **empty string**.

```
[
  {
    'a':null,
    'b':null
  },
  {
    'a':'1',
    'b':'2'
  }
]
```

I use a JsonSplitter to split the array so each element in the JSON array is handled separately.

In the first EvaluateJsonPath I do the following.

```
a=$.a
b=$.b
```

In the RouteToAttribute (I am using the same property, if I use a different or new property, I get the same issue)

```
a=${a:isEmpty():ifElse('NOT PROTECTED', 'PROTECTED')}
b=${b:isEmpty():ifElse('', 'ACTIVE')}
```

The RouteToAttribute processor is providing the following error for both properties:

> 'a' validated against '${a:isEmpty():ifElse('NOT PROTECTED', 'PROTECTED')}' is invalid because Expected Attribute Query to return type BOOLEAN but query returns type STRING
> 'b' validated against '${b:isEmpty():ifElse('', 'ACTIVE')}' is invalid because Expected Attribute Query to return type BOOLEAN but query returns type STRING

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

You are using RouteOnAttribute, but it looks like you are trying to replace attribute values. This is not what RouteOnAttribute does.

RouteOnAttribute is designed to evaluate a query, and then route matching FlowFiles to a specified relationship.

With RouteOnAttribute you have 3 options for the `Routing Strategy` which are

1. Route to Property name
2. Route to 'matched' if all match
3. Route to 'matched' if any matches

When using option 1, that is, `Route to Property name`, the NAME of the property is the RELATIONSHIP that the FlowFile will be routed to. The VALUE of the property is a QUERY that must return a BOOLEAN (true or false). If the result of the query is True, the FlowFile is routed to this relationship. If you have multiple properties configured, it will evaluate them in order.

When using option 2 or 3, you do not specify the name of the relationship, it is always called `matched`. You can specify multiple properties, and the NAME of the property is irrelevent. The VALUE of the property is a QUERY that must return a BOOLEAN. With option 2, if ALL of the queries return True, the FlowFile is routed to `matched`. With option 3, if ANY of the queries return True, the FlowFile is routed to `matched`.

[Read the documentation.](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/index.html)

Your error is caused because `${a:isEmpty():ifElse('NOT PROTECTED', 'PROTECTED')}` does not return a BOOLEAN. It returns a STRING. There is nothing RouteOnAttribute can do with this result.

Either way, you would be better off looking at Records.

Specifically, if you want to update the value of fields inside the data, look at [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html).

If you want to do routing logic on fields inside the data, look at [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) and [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html).

Splitting each JSON element out using SplitJson is inefficient and avoidable when using Records.